# How do I get RecyclerView to use items from SQLite Database in a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm building a simple information app about Cyber Security using Java in Android Studio to demonstrate how I've used Room, ViewModel, LiveData and RecyclerView. My knowledge of AndroidStudio is not great and I am still learning. I'm finding it very hard but I'm determined to keep going.

The main issue I am having is getting my items from my database to show in the recyclerViews in my different fragments. (I followed much of this YouTube playlist to learn and help  guide myself: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARpn-1FPNE4)

At first I tried creating the RecyclerView inside the Fragement's 'onCreateView' method, but I was having trouble getting 'adapter.setItems(items)' to work, as in the videos he seems to put it into the 'onChanged' method inside the MainActivity where he assigns the 'itemViewModel'.

After getting frustrated with this I thought I would try to simplify it by transferring the code to the MainActivity, like he has in the video. If I could get the recyclerView working in there then at least I'd know it was working outside of the fragments. However, my current activity_main.xml file is used to implement a slide-out NavigationView menu, so I wondered if I could put "R.id.cybervuls_recyclerview" into where I create the recyclerview and hoped it would send the data there instead.

Right now AndroidStudio tells me I have 0 major errors, but when I run the app on my phone it installs, opens and then immediately closes.
In Logcat I get the following error:

```
2020-05-16 23:17:17.579 11987-11987/com.example.hackinginfoapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.hackinginfoapp, PID: 11987
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hackinginfoapp/com.example.hackinginfoapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3303)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3411)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1994)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.hackinginfoapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7383)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1218)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3256)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3411) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1994) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

Here is my code for what I think are the relevant classes to this problem. I'd post all of the classes, but the post would get very lengthy and I'm not sure how else I could show all of the code.

MainActivity code (excluding implementation of the toolbar/navigation-menu):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private DrawerLayout drawer;

    private ItemViewModel itemViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.cybervuls_recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this)); //TODO - This is causing a crash
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        final ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter();

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        itemViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this,
                ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(this.getApplication())).get(ItemViewModel.class);
        itemViewModel.getAllItems().observe(this, new Observer<List<Item>>() {

            //This class is called every time the data in our LiveData is changed
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Item> items) {
                adapter.setItems(items);
            }
        });
```

Item code

```
package com.example.hackinginfoapp.roomdatabase;


import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

@Entity(tableName = "item_table")
public class Item {

    @PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    private String title;

    private String text;


    private String picturename;

    //constructor
    public Item(String title, String text, String picturename) {
        this.title = title;
        this.text = text;
        this.picturename = picturename;
    }

    //setter for Database to generate the id
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    //getters
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public String getPicturename() {
        return picturename;
    }
}
```

ItemAdapter code

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ItemHolder> {

    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new ItemHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemHolder holder, int position) {
        Item currentItem = items.get(position);
        holder.textViewTitle.setText(currentItem.getTitle());
        holder.textViewText.setText(currentItem.getText());
        holder.imageViewImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_protect);// TODO: Figure out how to dynamically assign images based on their Picturename
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView imageViewImage;
        private TextView textViewTitle;
        private TextView textViewText;

        public ItemHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_title);
            textViewText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_text);
            imageViewImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview_image);

        }
    }
}
```

One of my fragment's code (All fragments are currently the same as this)

```
public class CyberVulsFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cybervuls, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is Null pointer exception (NPE) which means you're trying to use the Recycler view in the Activity.onCreate method but the Recycler view is not actually present in the Activity xml file, probably you moved the code from the java file from Fragment to Activity but not the xml files.
Can you confirm this?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Boda.
I'm not sure what you mean by this, but I tried adding a recyclerview to my activity_main.xml file (https://i.imgur.com/YFSYxKP.png) and then assigning the recyclerView in my MainActivity.java file to the one in my activity_main.xml file (https://i.imgur.com/czZcKxP.png)

The recyclerView works in my activity_main.xml (https://i.imgur.com/w2224gA.png) to an extent and I can still pull out my navigation bar (https://i.imgur.com/SQEKWha.png).

What I want to be able to do now though is get the recyclerView to work in my other fragments.